# Flipping AVFrame while scaling

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, libav

I'm getting frames from web camera flipped vertically and I need to flip them if possible while resizing it in the same step.
Can somebody give me an example of it. Here is my code

```
AVFrame* inpic = av_frame_alloc();
avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)inpic,
    m_CurrentFrame.bits(),
    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32,
    m_CurrentFrame.width(),
    m_CurrentFrame.height());

AVFrame* m_resizedFrame = av_frame_alloc();
int num_bytes = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, m_szFrameSize.width(), m_szFrameSize.height());
uint8_t *m_resizedFrame_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(num_bytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)m_resizedFrame, m_resizedFrame_buffer, 
AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, m_szFrameSize.width(), m_szFrameSize.height());

SwsContext *resize = sws_getContext(m_CurrentFrame.width(),
m_CurrentFrame.height(), 
AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32, 
m_szFrameSize.width(), 
m_szFrameSize.height(), 
AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 
SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

sws_scale(resize, inpic->data, inpic->linesize, 0, 
m_CurrentFrame.height(), 
m_resizedFrame->data, 
m_resizedFrame->linesize);

//Do work with resized frame...
```

Thanks.